# Online identity verification solution

Tags: python, identity, verification

I am building a Python web application and we will need a user identity verification solution... something to verify the users identity during account registration.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience in integrating such a solution. What vendors/products out there have worked well with you? Any tips?

I don't have any experience in this matter so feel free to let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to implement a verification system, the concept is quite simple but actually building can be a hassle, especially if you are doing it from scratch.

The best way to approach this is to find a framework that handles the aspect of verification. Turbogears and Pylons are both capable of this rather than doing it yourself or using third party apps.

Personally I have worked on commercial projects using both frameworks and was able to sort out verification quite easily.

User verification utilizes specific concepts and low level technology such as: the internet's stateless characteristic, session handling, database design, etc...

So the point I am making is that it would be better if you rather got a good, stable framework that could do the dirty work for you.

By the way what framework are you thinking of using? That would help me give a more detailed answer.

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at WS-Trust.
A implementation of that is Windows Identity Foundation. But I'm sure You'll find more.

Answer (score 0):

We've found [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) easy both for the developer and for users.

Answer (score 0):

While not python-specific, [Trulioo](https://www.trulioo.com/) provides a very robust online identity verification API.

You can integrate with the [Trulioo API](https://www.trulioo.com/developers/identity-verification/) and instantly verify over five billion individuals and 250 million organizations. Although you can use the API with various ways (Python as well), there are a couple of quick-start projects that make integration easy.

If you are using npm, you can run `npm i trulioo` to install [the EmbedID component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trulioo-react).

Install [trulioo-react](https://github.com/Trulioo/trulioo-react):

`npm install trulioo-react`

Then in your jsx:

```
import EmbedID from 'trulioo-react/EmbedID'

const handleResponse = (e) => {
    // handle verification submission result here ...
}

<EmbedID url='URL' handleResponse={handleResponse} />
```

`handleResponse` is the callback from the vendor, here's [more info of what's](https://developer.trulioo.com/docs/identity-verification-step-6-verify) the response structure about.

To avoid [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues, you will need a backend server; you can either build your own or use [trulioo-react-sample-app](https://github.com/Trulioo/trulioo-react-sample-app):

```
TRULIOO_BASE_URL=
TRULIOO_USERNAME=
TRULIOO_PASSWORD=
TRULIOO_PORT=
SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM=
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH=
```

Simply run the following command in your cmd/terminal and enjoy the ride.

```
# install the libraries needed
npm i
# start the server
npm start
```

[image]

---

Disclaimer: I work for Trulioo and I am the author of `trulioo-react` and `trulioo-react-sample-app` projects.

Comment: Problem with trulioo is that you have to do tons of custom work on your own side for each country,.. It is not all in one solution. And their response is very slow. Takes 7 days to respond to trivial questions or queries. Also huge issues with communication and not knowing that issues are on their side (config took 1 week to set up, while constantly claiming it's problem on our side etc)..

Comment: @sensei I am sorry to hear your past experience with trying to utilize the Trulioo GlobalGateway API. EmbedID, along-side with new open source SDKs, tries to bridge this caveat and significantly reduce on-boarding times for developers. I would personally be more than happy to help you tackle any problems you might face on your on-boarding and utilizing EmbedID.